# json encoded php array wrapping quotes around coordinates variable output

Tags: php, json

I am writing a wordpress loop, which gets multiple posts and outputs the post custom field GeoJson coordinates array inside a php based array.

See below the contents of `$sFeatureCoordinates` variable.

```
  [
    [
      -0.7332730293273926,
      51.89886634382943
    ],
    [
      -0.7326534390449524,
      51.89770778622719
    ],
    [
      -0.7318434119224548,
      51.898079355455344
    ],
    [
      -0.7332730293273926,
      51.89886634382943
    ]
  ]
```

Then see below my php array which I am then using `json_encode` to format the array.

```
$arr = [
    'type' => 'FeatureCollection',
    'features' => []
];

// loop through each post
while($oQuery->have_posts()): $oQuery->the_post();

    // grab our type and coordinates
    $sFeatureType = get_field('geojson_feature_type');
    $sFeatureCoordinates = get_field('geojson_feature_coordinates');

    // add this to our features
    $arr['features'][] = [
        'type' => 'Feature',
        'properties' => [
            'id' => get_the_id(),
            'name' => get_the_title()
        ],
        'geometry' => [
            'type' => $sFeatureType,
            'coordinates' => [
                [ preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $sFeatureCoordinates) ]
            ]
        ]
    ];

endwhile;

$json = json_encode($arr);
```

Here is a sample of my json outputted from the array above http://myjson.com/pssis

The issue I am having is that the `coordinates` is getting wrapped in quotes when its getting encoded.

Which causes an js error when my google maps script tries to read it.

Any ideas on how I can stop my `coordinates` content from being wrapped in quotes upon `json_encode`?

Many Thanks

Comment: What is the JS error you are getting?

Comment: here is the error its definitely because the array is not valid geojson format https://justpaste.it/3uatf

Comment: `GeoJson coordinates array` is not an array if it was `preg_replace` would explode on the multi-dimensional array. AKA (Array to string conversion)

Comment: ArtisticPhoenix so i need to make it into a valid array before it goes to my $arr, because its a currently string.. ok I will try and do this

Comment: have you got any ideas on how to make my string into an array based on its current format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$sFeatureCoordinates` is JSON so just decode it and add to the array. Then it all works out when you `json_encode`.  Add or remove `[ ]` as needed to get the proper nesting level:

```
'coordinates' => [ [ json_decode($sFeatureCoordinates, true) ] ]
```

Comment: thanks for you help man for some reason `null` is being returned http://myjson.com/b3dvo

Comment: json_decode should turn my json format string to an php array, but it just returns null

Comment: Not sure where you're going wrong but check here: https://3v4l.org/aHLaR

Comment: I was literally just creating an online php demo... hoping for the same error as mine but yours is working fine.. gimme 5 see if i figure this out based off your demo thanks

Comment: `null` would mean invalid JSON so maybe one of the rows that you are testing isn't valid JSON.  You should do a test for `null` and then check the db.

Comment: Mate it works a charm. I worked what was wrong I was missing a set of wrapping `[ ]` in my string on wordpress. So without these extra wrapping bracket it was a valid array I guess. Thanks for patients and help. Working perfect now cheers.